# Bitnami phpMyAdmin 404

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I just set up a new Wordpress site in Lightsail using Bitnami. I've created the SSH Tunnel, and can access the site via 127... Everything looks good.

Except, http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpMyAdmin returns a page not found. The 404 page is obviously wrapped in my WP site, so I'm not sure what's missing here.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

For anyone wondering, it's changing the *phpMyAdmin* to *phpmyadmin*

Answer (score 0):

Never discount PEBCAK errors.... They're always the most difficult to solve.

I forgot that Linux was case sensitive. *bans self indefinitely*